# Is my proof showing $A$ and $B$ are invertible if $AB$ is invertible correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations

$V$ is a finite dimensional vector space and $A, B \in \mathcal{L} (V)$ where $\mathcal{L}$ is the space of linear operators. The question precisely asks to prove the statement either ways (iff statement). I have no problem proving that if $A^{-1}$ and $B^{-1}$ exist $\implies$ $(AB)^{-1}$ exists and that $(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}$. My question is for the backward direction, for which I have used to following argument:

*If $(AB)^{-1}$ exists then $(AB)^{-1}AB=AB(AB)^{-1}=I$*

*Assume $S, T \in \mathcal{L}$  such that  $AS=SA=I$ and $BT=TB=I$, then $S=A^{-1}$ and $T=B^{-1}$ since the inverse is unique.*

*From the first equation we have $S=B(AB)^{-1}$ and $T=(AB)^{-1}A$, then*

*$A^{-1}$ and $B^{-1}$ exist, completing the proof in the backward direction.*

Is my logic ok? Because I can't seem to find this answer anywhere.

Comment: You are assuming the existence of $S$ and $T$, which is what you need to prove. The computation that you need to do is to verify that $B(AB)^{-1}$ is actually the inverse of $A$ etc.

Comment: You checked that $AS = I$ holds with $S = B(AB)^{-1}$, but how do you know that $SA = I$ as well?

Comment: The right place to start is "Assume that $(AB)^{-1}$. We seek to show that $A^{-1}$ and $B^{-1}$ both exist." And here's a hint: you've never used the fact that $V$ is finite dimensional anywhere. Maybe you should use that...

Comment: When you wrote $AB^{-1}$, what you meant was $(AB)^{-1}$.

Comment: When you say, " Assume $S\in \mathcal{L}$ such that $AS=SA=I$" you are assuming that $A$ is invertible, which is what you are supposed to prove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have found a candidate for the inverse of $A$ to be $B(AB)^{-1}$.

This is, in fact, a right inverse since $A (B(AB)^{-1})=(AB)(AB)^{-1}=I$.

Now we need to use that the space is finite dimensional.

Since $A$ has a right inverse, its range is the whole space. Therefore its kernel is zero since the dimension of the space is finite.

This means that multiplication by $A$ is surjective and injective. Therefore it has an inverse.

For $B$ the argument is similar. $(AB)^{-1}A$ is a left inverse of $B$. Therefore the kernel of $B$ is zero. Using that the space is finite dimensional we get that the range is the whole space. Therefore it has an inverse too.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Consider, on the vector space of all sequences of real numbers, the transformation  $B$ that takes $u_1, u_2, u_3, \ldots$ to $0, u_1, u_2, u_3, \ldots$ (i.e., it prepends a zero) and $A$, which takes $u_1, u_2, u_3, \ldots$ to $u_2, u_3, \ldots$ (i.e., it strips off the first element).

Then $AB = I$. But $A$ is not invertible.

From this, you see that the hypothesis "$V$ is finite dimensional" is actually necessary. So perhaps start with asking yourself, "What main theorems do I know about transformations on finite dimensional vector spaces?" (... and about composite transformations, while you're at it.)

Answer (score 2):

Note that this fails for infinite-dimensonal spaces $V$, e.g. take $V= \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ and define $A(x_0, x_1, x_2, \ldots) = (0, x_0, x_1, x_2, \ldots)$ and $B(x_0, x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots) = (x_1 ,x_2, x_3, \ldots)$. Then $B \circ A$ is the identity but $A$ and $B$ are both not invertible, as $B$ is not onto and $A$ is not injective.

For finite dimensional spaces this canot happen as then $\dim(\operatorname{ker}(A)) + \dim(\operatorname{Im}(A)) = n$ for $A: V \to V$ linear and $\dim(V) = n$.
$A$ is injective iff $\operatorname{ker}(A) = \{0\}$ iff $\dim(\operatorname{Im}(A)) = n$ iff $A$ is onto.

And $AB$ invertible means $AB$ is injective and so $B$ is injective. (if $x \in \operatorname{ker}(B)$ then $x \in \operatorname{ker}(AB) = \{0\}$.) So $B$ is onto as well by the finite-dimensionality argument, hence invertible. So $A = (AB)B^{-1}$ is invertible as the product of invertible maps.